# Regex Find Text Between Previous Period and String

Tags: regex

Example Text:  "This is the beginning.  First group of words.  Second plain sentence.  Another set of words."

Pattern logic:  Match anything between the word "sentence" and the preceding period.  The match may extend multiple lines.

Desired match:  "  Second plain "

Note:  Match should not include quotation marks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is pretty simple:

```
\.([^.]+?)sentence
```

the match is the first group ($1)

Comment: That matches from from the first dot?

Comment: This regex suffers the same flaw as my own attempts.  It matches everything between the first period and the word "sentence".  I need to return everything between the immediate previous period.

This regex matches:  ". First group of words. Second plain sentence"

I need it to match: "  Second plain "

Comment: @s15199d you are welcome, please mark my answer as solution :)

Answer (score 0):

without grouping, using look ahead (zero width)

```
 [^.]*(?=sentence)
```